# Clearing from data (input search bar)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<form class="form-inline" action="javascript:function()" >
<input id="searchKey2" type="text" class="pageSearchBar "  >
</form>
```

I have an input search bar like the above, each time I search I want the search query to be deleted from the bar but I am not sure on how to do it in JavaScript.

Also is there a way to set the form value, except `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML`?

Comment: Learn Javascript, please. After completing some good tutorials, you will get your answers. Note: no, I am not being rude.

Comment: Yes he's right, look at some good tutorial first. As shown in the answer below, the text input field has a value property, you want to use. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set the form field, you can do this

```
document.getElementById('searchKey2').value = 'something';
```